# what's the difference between these two low pass filter types

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

Is there any difference between these two types of lowpass filters?  I see the equation is the same, I assume they're both first order then.  Just curious if there's any practical difference.  Maybe one allows me to set gain and the other doesn't?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For one, the top one is inverting and the bottom is non-inverting.

Comment: Also, the top one can have passband gain, while the lower one has gain of 1.

Comment: @confused, you might be interested in this book from TI: [PLL Performance, Simulation, and Design Handbook](http://www.ti.com/tool/pll_book)

Comment: @ThePhoton I take it that the second comment was meant for confused's other question about PLL's?

Comment: @helloworld922, I'm assuming this question is also about PLLs (specifically, about the loop filter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write their transfer function from input to the output.

The first is a active filter, assume a ideal Op amp:

$$
H(s)=\frac{-R_{2}}{R_{1}} \times \frac{1}{1+R_{2}C_{2}s}
$$

The second it's basically passive RC filter followed by a voltage follower.:

$$
H(s)=\frac{1}{RCs+1}
$$

Then, you can see some differences, such as the first one has negative gain and can have non-unity gain at low frequency.